# PHP: Datepicker doesn't work and button shows error

Tags: php, button, datepicker, parse-error

I have 2 problems in my code. But first here's the complete set of code

```
<html>

<title>IMS:MPP | Home</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

        function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) 
            {
                var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
                var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
                var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
            } 

            var state = new Array();
            for (i=0; i<1; i++) {
                state[i] = "none";
                }



</script>

<head>
<link href="officerStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){

        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"inputField",
            cellColorScheme: "armygreen",
            limitToToday:true,
        });
            };

            $(function() {
            $("#inputField1").JsDatePick();
            }
            )
            ;


            </script>



<!-- End -->

<?php


if(isset($_REQUEST['inputField1']))
    $inputField1 = $_REQUEST['inputField1'];
else
    $inputField1 = "";

include('global.php');

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="mpp"; // Database name
$tbl_name="userinfo"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

//$_SESSION['myusername'] = $row['Username'];

//$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $row['UserID'];
$myusername=$_SESSION['myusername'];
//$mypassword=$_SESSION['mypassword'];

//require("mainlogin.php"); 
//$id = $_SESSION['myusername']; //Get user's ID 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where Username='$myusername'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

$type = $row['UserType'];
?>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <img id="logos" src="images/logo.png" style="opacity:0.7;filter:alpha(opacity=70)"
        onmouseover="this.style.opacity=0.7;this.filters.alpha.opacity=70"
        onmouseout="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" border="none"/>

    <a href="logout.php" onclick="return confirm ('Are you sure you want to Log Out?')"><img id="out" src="images/Outbtn.png" style="opacity:0.7;filter:alpha(opacity=70)"
                onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100"
                onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0.7;this.filters.alpha.opacity=70" border="none"/></a>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-bgbtm">
            <div id="menu">

                <?php

                /*------------------------------------------------------------ Encoder ------------------------------------------------------------*/

                    if ($type=="Encoder"){
                    //Navigation
                        echo "  <ul>
                                <li class='current_page_item'> <a href='#'>Home</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href='SalesOfficer.php'>Sales</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href='PromoOfficer.php'>Promo</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href='BankOfficer.php'>Bank</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href='PlanOfficer.php'>Plan</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href='User.php'>User</a> </li>
                                <li> <a href='Client.php'>Client</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                                </div>";

                    //Texts
                        echo "  <br/><br/><h1 class='title'><a href='#'>Welcome</a></h1>
                        <div class='entry'>";
                        echo "<h3>" . $row['UserType'] . "&nbsp" . $row['FirstName'] . "</h3>";

                        echo "<div class='post'></br>
                        <h3 class='title'>TODAY: Walk-In Clients</a></h3>";
                        echo "<h4 class ='title'>" . date("F d, Y") . date(" (D)");
                        echo "</h4></div>";

                    //TableHeader   
                        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5'>
                        <tr>
                         <th>Time In</th>
                         <th>Last Name</th>
                         <th>First Name</th>
                         <th>Middle Name</th>
                         <th>Promo Officer Name</th>
                         <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>";         

            /*------------------------------------------------------------ GoToDateTable ------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

                    //GoToDate

                        echo "  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='jsDatePick_ltr.min.css' />";

                        echo"<form name='sdate' action='#' method='post'>";
                        echo"<input type='text' size='12' id='inputField' name='inputField1'>";
                        echo"<a href='#' onclick='validateForm(document.forms['sdate'].action);return false;><img src='images/go.png' height='27' width='60'></a>";

                    //GoToDateQuery

                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT TimeIn,LastName, FirstName, MiddleName ,PromoOfficerName FROM timein WHERE DateTrans='".$inputField1."'");


                    //TableAlternateFieldColor                  
                        $sw = 0;
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                    if($sw == 0) 
                                        {
                                            $mycolor = "#fff";
                                            $sw = 1;
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            $mycolor = "#79b669";
                                            $sw = 0;
                                        }


                    //TableRowAndTableData                  
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='".$mycolor."'>"; 
                                echo "<td>" . $row['TimeIn'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['MiddleName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['PromoOfficerName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><image src='images/out.png' height=27 width=60></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                        }

            /*------------------------------------------------------------ DateTodayTable ------------------------------------------------------------*/    

                        $datetoday=date("m.d.Y");
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT TimeIn,LastName, FirstName, MiddleName ,PromoOfficerName FROM timein WHERE DateTrans='".$datetoday."'");

                        $sw = 0;
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                    if($sw == 0) 
                                        {
                                            $mycolor = "#fff";
                                            $sw = 1;
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            $mycolor = "#79b669";
                                            $sw = 0;
                                        }
                                echo "<tr bgcolor='".$mycolor."'>"; 

                                echo "<td>" . $row['TimeIn'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['MiddleName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['PromoOfficerName'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td> <a href='#' onclick = PopupCenter('timeoutform.php?salesID=<?$row['PlanHoldersID']?>','myPop1',400,430)><image src='images/out.png' height=27 width=60> </a> </td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                        echo "<a href='#' onclick = PopupCenter('timeinform.php','myPop1',400,430)> <img src = 'images/add.png' height='27' width='60'> </a>";  
                    }   

            /*------------------------------------------------------------ Administrator ------------------------------------------------------------*/                 

                    elseif ($type=="Administrator"){
                        echo "<ul>
                              <li class='current_page_item'> <a href='#'>Home</a> </li>
                              <li> <a href='#'>Daily</a> </li>
                              <li> <a href='#'>Weekly</a> </li>
                              <li> <a href='#'>Commission</a> </li>
                              <li> <a href='#'>Client</a> </li>
                              </ul> </div>";

                        echo "  <br/><br/><h1 class='title'><a href='#'>Welcome</a></h1>
                        <div class='entry'>";
                        echo "<h3>" . $row['UserType'] . "&nbsp" . $row['FirstName'] . "</h3>";

                    }
                ?>  

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer-wrapper">
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2010 Sitename.com. All rights reserved. Design by FCT.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

**Problem 1:**

```
//GoToDate

                        echo "  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='jsDatePick_ltr.min.css' />";

                        echo"<form name='sdate' action='#' method='post'>";
                        echo"<input type='text' size='12' id='inputField' name='inputField1'>";
                        echo"<a href='#' onclick='validateForm(document.forms['sdate'].action);return false;><img src='images/go.png' height='27' width='60'></a>";
```

This is a textbox which gets the date and a button which triggers the query to show the data under the given date. The problem is it works when date is manually entered but it doesn't when the datepicker is used.

**Problem 2:**

```
echo "<td> <a href='#' onclick = PopupCenter('timeoutform.php?salesID=<?$row['PlanHoldersID']?>','myPop1',400,430)><image src='images/out.png' height=27 width=60> </a> </td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
```

This button should show `timeoutform.php` yet it shows the ff. errors

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or`T_VARIABLE' or
>   `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\wamp\www\IMS-MPP(Encoder)\home.php on line 209

**Hope someone could help. Thanks a lot!**

Comment: For your second problem try this: echo "<td> <a href='#' onclick = PopupCenter('timeoutform.php?salesID=" . $row['PlanHoldersID'] . "','myPop1',400,430)><image src='images/out.png' height=27 width=60> </a> </td>"; off course there is a security risk here. Mind that!

Comment: First fix all error messages. If you have a problem to understand it, please explain which part of the error message is not clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

"No need to write `<?$row['PlanHoldersID']?>`

replace with **".$row['PlanHoldersID']."**

```
echo "<td> <a href='#' onclick = PopupCenter('timeoutform.php?salesID=".$row['PlanHoldersID'].",'myPop1',400,430)><image src='images/out.png' height=27 width=60> </a> </td>";
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use double quotes to wrap around the variable rather than single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

For problem 2, you've got some wonky formatting. Try this:

```
echo "<td> <a href='#' onclick = PopupCenter('timeoutform.php?salesID=".$row['PlanHoldersID']."','myPop1',400,430)><image src='images/out.png' height=27 width=60> </a> </td>";
```

Basically, PHP was printing `"<?$row['PlanHoldersID']?>"` as a string inside the HTML.

Comment: thank you so much :) hope you could help me also on problem1 :D

Comment: @zeroSeven It looks like datepicker is specific to jQuery. I would add some tags about jQuery and Javascript so that people who know it more can help you there.